# Apache POI word best way to add text after table

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

What is the best or short way to add text after table? Not in table but after.
The table is in the docx file.

So, example:

- textA
- textB
- Table
- textC
- textD

I want to add some text between the Table and textC.
Result:

- textA
- textB
- Table
- inserted new text
- textC
- textD

I tried following code but it's insert before the table not after.

```
 XmlCursor cursor =  table.getCTTbl().newCursor(); 
 XWPFParagraph newParagraph = doc.insertNewParagraph(cursor); 
 XWPFRun run = newParagraph.createRun(); 
 run.setText("inserted new text");
```

Comment: Create a `XWPFParagraph` after the table and then `XWPFRun`s containing the text in this paragraph.

Comment: Ok, but how can I set the position of the XWPFParagraph? I tried this: XmlCursor cursor =  table.getCTTbl().newCursor() but is the before position of the table.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code you are using. Also explain more in detail what you are doing. Where is the table coming from? How are you getting the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used just below code and fixed

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The approach using a [XmlCursor](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlCursor.html) is correct. Read more about this `XmlCursor` and it's methods in the linked document.

So we need jumping to the end of the `CTTbl` and then finding the next element's start tag.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordTextAfterTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordTextAfterTable.docx"));

  XWPFTable table = document.getTableArray(0);

  org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = table.getCTTbl().newCursor();
  cursor.toEndToken(); //now we are at end of the CTTbl
  //there always must be a next start token. Either a p or at least sectPr.
  while(cursor.toNextToken() != org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor.TokenType.START);
  XWPFParagraph newParagraph = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
  XWPFRun run = newParagraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("inserted new text");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordTextAfterTableNew.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this  works for me:

```
                 tablasolicitantecargo = tablafiladoss.getTable();
                 org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = tablasolicitantecargo.getCTTbl().newCursor();
                 cursor.toEndToken();
                 while(cursor.toNextToken() != org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor.TokenType.START);
                 XWPFParagraph newParagraph = requisicionesaprobadas.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
                 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                 XWPFRun run = newParagraph.createRun();
```